How to group by and aggregate Int field and array[int] fields?
So, lets say I've got some table with 2 fields - first_col is int and second_col is array[int]:
from sqlalchemy import (
    Table,
    select,
    Integer,
)
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY



some_table = Table(
    "some_table",
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("first_col", Integer),
    Column("second_col", ARRAY(Integer)),
)

And, I want to take all objects from the db with both first_col and second_col and like aggregate them, I can show what I want in python code:
def get_some_stuff_and_aggregate() -> dict:
    query = (
        select(
            [
                some_table.c.first_col,
                some_table.c.second_col,
            ]
        )
        .select_from(some_table)
    )
    # execute query here... it's not important here
    query_res = ...

    res_dict = {}
    for some_obj in query_res:
        for some_ids in (
            [some_obj.first_col],
            some_obj.second_col,
        ):
            for some_id in some_ids:
                if some_id in res_dict:
                    res_dict[some_id] += 1
                else:
                    res_dict[some_id] = 1

    return res_dict

But, I guess I can do this at the SQL (ORM) level without this dirty and slow python aggregation, can you please help me? How to do it better, using ORM?

So you want the count of the number of times each value appears in either first col or second col?

Yes, exactly, what you are sayin is correct

There is probably a better SQL, but this seems to do what I think you ask for.
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, MetaData, Table, create_engine, func, insert, select
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY, array
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://")
metadata = MetaData()
some_table = Table(
    "some_table",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("first_col", Integer),
    Column("second_col", ARRAY(Integer)),
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

dummy_data = [
    {"first_col": 1, "second_col": [1, 2, 1, 4, 5]},
    {"first_col": 3, "second_col": [2, 4, 6, 2, 10]},
    {"first_col": 6, "second_col": [3, 6, 9, 3, 15]},
    {"first_col": 4, "second_col": [4, 8, 4, 16, 20]},
    {"first_col": 2, "second_col": [5, 10, 15, 5, 25]},
]

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(insert(some_table).values(dummy_data))
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    subq = select(
        func.unnest(
            some_table.c.second_col.op("||")(array([some_table.c.first_col]))
        ).label("element")
    ).subquery()

    statement = select(subq.c.element, func.count("*")).group_by(subq.c.element)

    for i in session.execute(statement):
        print(i)

This generates the following sql and output.
SELECT
    anon_1.element,
    count(% (count_2)
        s::VARCHAR) AS count_1
FROM (
    SELECT
        unnest(some_table.second_col || ARRAY [some_table.first_col]) AS element
    FROM
        some_table) AS anon_1
GROUP BY
    anon_1.element

(9, 1)
(15, 2)
(3, 3)
(5, 3)
(4, 5)
(10, 2)
(6, 3)
(2, 4)
(16, 1)
(25, 1)
(20, 1)
(1, 3)
(8, 1)

